How to solve a non-homogenous differential equation with constant particular solution
I am trying to solve the following second-order differential equation:
$m \ddot{x}=6\pi \eta r(100-\dot{x})$
where , , and  are constants.
I am unsure how to solve this problem, the homogeneous part I can manage but I have no clue about the non-homogeneous part.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Change to $y= x - 100 t$.

$x$ is function of what variable?

x is a function of t
